# How can I loop a vlookup that sums data across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that looks up a value from the first sheets across multiple sheets, and then sum the returned values. One variable is that the number of sheets I'm looking up across isn't static and will have different sheet names.

This is what I tried, but I think I'm missing some core concepts around how Application.vlookup functions.

```vb
Sub lookupSum()
    Dim myVlookupResult As Long
    Dim myTableArray As Range
    Dim myVlookupSum As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    count = Sheets.count
    i = 2
    Do While i <= count
        Sheets(1).Select
        With Worksheets(i)
            Set myTableArray = .Range("A:N")
        End With

        myVlookupResult = Application.vlookup(Range("A2"), myTableArray, 5, False)

        myVlookupSum = myVlookupSum + myVlookupResult
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox myVlookupSum

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem?  What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @TimWilliams It returns a 0 in the message box

Comment: If you add `Debug.Print myVlookupResult ` inside the loop what do you see?  Is it always zero?

Comment: I just tried this on my home machine and got an error "Type mismatch (Error 13)" on `myVlookupResult = Application.vlookup(Range("A2"), myTableArray, 5, False)`.

Comment: You're trying to assign the return value to a `Long` so maybe it's non-numeric?  Try to debug and see what's coming back from vlookup.  For example if there's no match you'll get an error value.

Comment: The values being pulled should all be numeric. I'll double check this on monday when I'm back on my other machine.

Comment: You don't need t and infact shouldn't be `Select`ing sheets. Be explicit with your declaration instead - eg. `Set ws = Sheets(i)` ... `ws.Range("A2")` ... and so on

Comment: @TimWilliams I ran this on a different set of data and got a value of 2 in the message box. Ran 'Debug.Print myVlookupResult' inside the loop and the values returned were:
    1
    0
    1

The Application.Vlookup() is supposed to run on three sheets at the moment and pull the value from the 5th column and sum it. The values in those 5th columns it should be pulling from would be: 0.56 0.47 0.53

Comment: If the values being summed are decimals then you should use Double, not Long.